# How to move buttons to the bottom of the dashboard Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-nestedscrollview

So i am trying to design a dashboard for my application and i am having some issues with the `button`. I wanted to move the buttons to the bottom of the page for the application im trying to make using Android Studio. I've used `alignparentbottom=true` but it doesn't work, the button only moved a li'l lower but not exactly on the bottom of my page

Here is the code for my buttons-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
android:layout_margin="9pt"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12pt"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/btnsmile"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:text="My Mood"

android:textColor="@color/lingkaran_smile"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btnsmile"
                                style="? 
                             android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

         android:background="@drawable/lingkaran_smile"

 android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_smile2"
                                android:indeterminate="false"
                                android:onClick="onclick"
                                android:padding="13dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="CONTENT HERE"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you need button at bottom and rest of screen in Scrolling Then this will help you..

Comment: If i wanted to continue using my codes is it possible to move the buttons to the bottom?i made 5 buttons in horizontal position

Comment: In your xml there to many layouts.. No need these all layout.. if you need to put 5 button at bottom tell me i provide you xml for that..

Comment: yes it would helped me so much if you can provide me the xml code with more simple and less layout, thank you so much

Comment: ive tried the code from above and it works.The buttons now moved to the bottom part of the page. But each button seems too close to each other and the position is way too left (not center). Ive tried using android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" but it doesnt work.Is there any way i can create a lil bit distance for each buttons and make the position better?

Comment: sorry, just a lil update i used android:layout_margin="10dp" and it works now each buttons has distance and looking better. Thank you so much again for your help Bro.God Bless and have a good day

Comment: If you are satify with my answer. Please provide green tick on this answer. Thanks .

Comment: Hey Kindly Accept this answer if it help you and close question now